# Why i cant add or substract two date times?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with the time and with the milliseconds in another columns like this:

```
  Time    ms
0 14:11:52  0
1 4:11:52   250
1 4:11:52   500
1 4:11:52   750
```

I want to add the milliseconds to the time like this:

```
 Time           
0 14:11:52  
1 4:11:52:250
1 4:11:52:500
1 4:11:52:750
```

I tried converting both to datetime[ns] and [D] but I get the following error: `cannot add DatetimeArray and DatetimeArrayt`

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
df['ms'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['ms'], format='%f')

df['Time'] = df['Time'] + df['ms']
```

I think that by using a time delta is possible to achieve what I want, but is there a cleaner way to just add one date column with another one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC two `to_timedelta`

```
pd.to_timedelta(df.Time)+pd.to_timedelta(df.ms,unit='ms')
Out[72]: 
0          14:11:52
1   04:11:52.250000
1   04:11:52.500000
1   04:11:52.750000
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
df['Time']=pd.to_timedelta(df.Time)+pd.to_timedelta(df.ms,unit='ms')
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas' time mangling principle is simple:

```
datetime - datetime = timedelta
datetime + timedelta = datetime
```

The rest of the combinations will not work at all, or at least not as expected.